# NuGet.Config file Transforms?

Tags: tfs, nuget, nuget-package-restore

Is there a way to transform a Nuget.Config file in a solution based on the solution configuration? I have one packageSource that I only use for resolving dependencies on my local machine. I don't want this packageSource to be used at all when I build the solution on the build server.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packageSources>
<clear />
<add key="MyLocalFeed" value="\\MyNetworkShare" />
<add key="CompanyFeed" value="http://companynugetserver/" />
</packageSources>
<solution>
<add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
</solution>

</configuration>
```

In the above sample Nuget.Config, I only want to use "MyLocalFeed" on my local development server ("Debug" configuration in the solution). Once all changes are checked-in and built on the build server, the "MyLocalFeed" packageSource should no longer appear/be ignored. I have to keep the `<clear />` statement in the config, per company requirements.

Comment: Why would you not want to be consistent in using the same NuGet feed for development and CI?

Comment: @DanielMann I'm trying to avoid uploading a huge number of incremental pre-release packages to the company feed. It's already very bloated and slow and the network share makes dependency resolution much easier in between builds on the build server.

Answer (score 1):

No, we cannot transform a `Nuget.Config` file in a solution based on the solution configuration.

Based on your description you can use the "`MyLocalFeed`" for local development, and   remove "`MyLocalFeed`" in the `Nuget.Config` file and use that file in TFS build to restore the packages from `CompanyFeed`.

But please note that the local packages may have other dependencies which are not included in `CompanyFeed`...

So we recommend using the **same NuGet feed** for development and CI, or you push all the  related packages into the`CompanyFeed`.